# iPhone programming-- UIView elements appear to be ignoring Hidden=NO calls

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

Using XCode 4.4 and Mountain Lion,

I have a UIImageView, and on that view, I have a UIProgressView and a UIButton.  When the app starts, the progress view and button are both hidden, as set in the storyboard.  I then try to unhide them, first the progress bar when I'm doing something, and then the button when I'm done.  I have called, for both items,

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:saveToCameraRoll];
```

to try to put them in front of the UIView.

Problem is, when I programmatically try to unhide them, it doesn't work.  I can call:

```
progressBar.hidden = NO;
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:progressBar];
```

And that does nothing.

So then I tried to set everything as *visibile* in the storyboard and then programmatically set everything to be invisible once the controller loads.  No deal; now my calls to hidden = YES seem to be ignored.

I then removed all actual programming, so that hitting buttons should just cause the button and progress bar to appear, reasoning that maybe the main thread was getting starved and couldn't update.

How can I force elements to pay attention to being hidden?

**EDIT**: I've now also tried programmatically modifying the alpha from 1 to 0.  No change.  It's like everything I'm doing is getting ignored.  I made these items via the ctrl-drag method into the @interface section of the .m file; maybe I don't have some more delegates or interfaces or whatever hooked up?

Comment: I'm really confused as to what you are doing, Why are you bringing the progress bar to the front (and possibly moving it to the back. When you add that view and a button added to the ImageView as subviews, they will be in front of the image. So just set hidden to YES or NO - that should be enough. If that is not working you have to make sure you really have a reference to it by say logging it hidden property before and after you set it.

Comment: @DavidH-- I would think that setting hidden to YES or NO would also do it, but it doesn't.  I can change the 'hidden' variable in the storyboard, but not in the program itself.  I can also debug into the program and see the program hit the hidden=YES or NO calls.

Comment: I don't use storyboards since I want full control. Sure you cannot get a reference to it. Perhaps using storyboards is limiting your ability too much. Well, that's why I made this a comment not an answer. Seriously, good luck!

Comment: @DavidH-- the kicker is that it worked for the first two times I tried it, and then the ability disappeared.  I may just have to delete everything and try again.  This is very irritating, to say the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible the outlets are nil because they aren't hooked up in IB?  If so, no amount of manipulation will have an effect.

Try `NSLog(@"%@", saveToCameraRoll);`

Is it null?  Fix by reconnecting outlets in IB.  If that works, then .hidden = NO will work and you can get rid of any code you added to manipulate the view hierarchy.

Comment: This turned out to be true for both components.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As you said that you connected the ivars with your XIB file, it seems like your problem is that you are doing stuff on the main thread which in return blocks the run loop and your UI doesn't get redrawn anymore. When you update UI elements by changing their properties, those changes aren't applied instantaneous but the next time the UI gets redrawn which only happens when you give the main threads runloop a chance to run. However, if you do something like the following code, the changes will never appear:

```
[button setHidden:YES];

[self doSomethingReallyExpensiveAndTimeConsuming];

[button setHidden:NO];
```

The result of this code is that the button is set to be hidden, but doesn't get redrawn because the system has no chance to do it and when the system actually has a chance to redraw the UI, the button is already set to be invisible. A fix for this is to either split the work up and schedule it via timers on the main thread, or to use something like GCD to offload the work on a secondary thread (but then you need to make sure that your code is threadsafe!)

Comment: I already have the work split.  Is there a way to say, "before you do anything else, just draw this component.  Then go about your business."

Comment: @mmr Not really... You could insert something like `[[NSRunLoop currentRunloop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]]`, but thats not exactly the cleanest solution

Comment: @JustSid-- fair enough.  I guess I need to run via NSTimers in order to put it in the app store anyway, so that it can be put into the background, right?  I'll do it that way, I guess.

Comment: @mmr The timer doesn't put it in the background but just delays the execution of the function to the future so that the system can redraw your UI in the meantime. That way you don't need to worry about thread safety, but(!), if the task takes a lot of time, iOS might kill your process for not responding anymore so maybe threads or a simple GCD queue might be the more correct solution for your problem

Comment: @JustSid-- ok, threads it is then.  The operation is pretty simple and straightforward, guess I'd best disable the UI while it runs though.  I really was hoping to avoid doing this, but oh well.

Comment: @JustSid-- also, you're answer is as correct as danh's, but I can only give one checkmark.  Sorry :(

Comment: @mmr No problem, I'm a bit confused though because your edit suggests that the outlets already were hooked up correctly... But I'm glad you got it working, good luck with your project!

Comment: @JustSid-- I fixed the outlets first, then noticed that you were also right.  I have many bugs, apparently.